# How to Generate Entity Classes using ORMLITE for database tables

Tags: java, orm, ormlite

How to run ORMLite Auto-Generator generate table entity class

Auto generate ORMLITE entity class.

I have tried below cmd but didn't work
"ormlite-autogen generate -c generator.properties" Where I can find "ORMLite Auto-Generator" dependencies

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.